# Centering a page in css

Tags: html, css

I want the content to be centred in the page. However, it doesn't seem to work.

CSS:

```
        body {
         text-align: center;
        }
        .velkommen {
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-size: 28px;
            width: 400px;
            background-color: rgb(240, 255, 240);
            -webkit-box-shadow: black;
            border-radius: 50px
        }
        #links {
            font-family: Verdana;
            width: 300px;
            padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
        }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="velkommen">Velkommen til min hjemmeside</div>
<div id="links">Links:<br>Random Page!</div>
```

Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/URdTD/

What is wrong?

Comment: what you want? the text within #links needs to be centered, please check the updated version [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/URdTD/4/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this style to the div:

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

Comment: What if I want to keep the width of the divs and center them?

Answer (score 3):

To remove even one more line you could use

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Just remember that you need to have a width on the element that you want to center.

Answer (score 1):

This dosnt work if u have "float:left" to the element that you want to center.

Remember that the content should have
1)margin: 0 auto;
2)width: some px;
3)no floats